# I want to set the color of points that represent pixels inside a list

Tags: c#, image, list, analysis, points

I have a list that contains points (x,y) from an image ( I save pixel coordinates in a list in the form of x and y) 
the thing I want to do is set the color of these pixels.
I created a new class PointPixel with main atributes x,y I didn't use the default Point class of c#.

So my problem is that I want to access the point directly inside the list ... so I don't use a bitmap instance to use the method SetPixel

Some code examples would be great thanks in advance

Comment: I am curious why you wouldn't want to directly use a `Bitmap`.

Comment: i am trying to develop a method to recognize object on an image. All these points pixels that are connected to eachother. Now that i have them all inside a list i want to try manipulate them like set the color and tale the distances between them

Comment: I think I understand. Your list of pixels is a path? If so, maybe you should check out [`System.Drawing.Drawing2D.GraphicsPath`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.drawing2d.graphicspath.aspx)

Comment: what you mean by path? all the items inside the list are list items and inside there contain instances from my PointPixel class with x and y. All the items aved inside the list are a sequence of pixels that eventualy will form for example a squear or other forms of pixels . I just have lists with x,y points so i want now to set a specific color to each of these lists so when i draw them on picture  i want to see basically the items on each lists with difrent color thanks very much in advance

Comment: I may be missing what you're intending to do. I'm merely suggesting that it sounds like you're trying to keep track of shapes, or paths, or pixels and color, but you are avoiding the facilities that are already available to you (GraphicsPath, Regions, etc)

Comment: do you have some code example so i can understand your logic with these classes ?

Answer (score 2):

Why not using an 2D-Array, where each point of the array corresponds to the coordinate of each pixel? Basically, that's what a Bitmap is.

Also, if you only store the coordinates, how are you going to define a color that doesn't exist?

```
Color[,] bitmap = new Color[xDimension, yDimension]();
bitmap[x, y] = new Color(r, g, b);
```

Is this what you're looking for?

Comment: i have 1 list that contains list on points like: GeneralList- contains   1list- contains x 210,y77 2list- contains x211,x77 and so on ... all these represent pixels of an image and i want to get that data from the lists and draw them with some color ... maybe i need to create a difrent setPixel method ?

Comment: @AlexManowar I'm not quite sure I understand your question. Now that I think of it, I don't remember seeing a question at all. What are you trying to do? `GeneralList[a][b].SetPixel(x, y)`??? Where do you intend to save the color?

Comment: i can't post the printscreen with my list structure i need more points :P